# Best pattern(s) to select an operation based on multiple conditions

Tags: c#, design-patterns, conditional-statements

I am trying to find the best suited pattern or patterns to a problem I'm facing.

As per title, I want to select an operation based on the value of some variables that can assume specific values from as many enums.
An example with the exact problem (but different values) I'm facing:

```
-variables-
shape: round, square, triangle
color: red, green, blue
dimensions: 2d, 3d

-operations-
rotate, scale, delete, etc..
```

Now, based on these 3 variables I want to select some specific operation that could be shared between combinations (eg: I want to rotate all green objects, delete it if red-3d-round and scale the 2d-blues) or could have different parameters based on the combination (eg: rotate 2d greens by 45°, rotate 3d greens by 90°)

Right now this is implemented as a series of if-else which is neither pleasant nor easy to maintain.
I though about using a combination of Strategy and some other pattern, or maybe going for a Builder but I'm nor really sure how to move around.

```
case SomeCase:
foreach(var item in items){
    if(item.Dimension == Dimensions.2D){
        if(item.Color == Colors.Green){
            item.Rotate(45);
        }
        else if(item.Color == Colors.Blue){
            item.Scale(2);
        }
    }
    else if(item.Dimension == Dimensions.3D){
        if(item.Color == Colors.Green){
            item.Rotate(90);
        }
        else if(item.Color == Colors.Red){
            if(item.Shape == Shapes.Round){
                item.Delete();
            }
            else if(item.Shape == Shapes.Square){
                item.Glow();
            }
        }
    }
}
break;
```

As a sidenote, while the possible values of the conditions are very likely to never change, new conditions could be added in the future and I would like to take this into consideration.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This can also be a chain of responsibility where each handler does an atomic job and passes the payload further the pipeline. However, without a code that would show what your arguments are, what structure you operate on and what output you expect, it's too generic. Please expand your question.

Comment: You are right, I have added some code example, thanks

Answer (score 2):

"Best pattern" is subjective, but if you're looking for something concise and easy to read, I'd suggest putting your operaions and conditions in a map/dictionary (wait for the really compact solution at the end):

```
Dictionary<Action<SomeItem>, Func<SomeItem, bool>[]> _operationConditions =
    new Dictionary<Action<SomeItem>, Func<SomeItem, bool>[]>
    {
        {
            item => item.Rotate(45),
            new Func<SomeItem, bool>[]
            {
                item => item.Color == Color.Green,
                item => item.Dimensions == Dimensions.Two
            }
        },
        {
            item => item.Delete(),
            new Func<SomeItem, bool>[]
            {
                item => item.Color == Color.Red,
                item => item.Dimensions == Dimensions.Three
            }
        }
    };
```

Then find the operation that matches your item (this executes all matching operations):

```
var operations = _operationConditions
    .Where(pair => pair.Value.All(condition => condition(item)))
    .Select(pair => pair.Key)
    .ToList();
foreach (var op in operations) op(item);
```

Then you just add more operations and conditions to the dictionary.

---

If you want to really spice it up and make it much easier to get an overview of all your operations and their conditions, we can introduce a class with extension methods for the SomeItem class:

```
static class If
{
    public static bool TwoDim(this SomeItem item)
        => item.Dimensions == Dimensions.Two;
    public static bool ThreeDim(this SomeItem item)
        => item.Dimensions == Dimensions.Three;
    
    public static bool Green(this SomeItem item)
        => item.Color == Color.Green;
    public static bool Red(this SomeItem item)
        => item.Color == Color.Red;
}

// And to get even fancier...

static class Do
{
    public static Action<SomeItem> Rotate(double degrees)
        => item => item.Rotate(degrees);
    public static Action<SomeItem> Delete()
        => item => item.Delete();
}
```

Now your dictionary can look like this:

```
Dictionary<Action<SomeItem>, Func<SomeItem, bool>[]> _operationConditions =
        new Dictionary<Action<SomeItem>, Func<SomeItem, bool>[]>
    {
        { Do.Rotate(45), new [] { If.TwoDim, If.Green } },
        { Do.Delete(), new [] { If.ThreeDim, If.Red } }
    };
```

Check out an example in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XBuK1I).

Answer (score 0):

There are several patterns that can be handy here: Command, Strategy, Rules Engine, etc.

The basic idea is more or less the same everywhere:

- The action and the related precondition should be next to each other
- The evaluation process should be separated from the above components

[image: The rules pattern's UML diagram]
(*Source: [Michael Whelan - The Rules Design Pattern](https://www.michael-whelan.net/rules-design-pattern/)*)

Let me show what I mean:

```
public interface ITransformation
{
   bool CanTransformationBeApplied(Shape item);
   void ApplyTransformation(Shape item);
}
```

```
public Rotate45DegreesTransformation: ITransformation
{
   public bool CanTransformationBeApplied(Shape item)
     => item.Dimension == Dimensions.2D && item.Color == Colors.Green;
    
   public void ApplyTransformation(Shape item)
     => item.Rotate(45);
}
```

```
public class TransformationsEvaluator
{
   private readonly ImmutableList<ITransformation> transforms = new List<ITransformation> 
   {
     new Rotate45DegreesTransformation(),
     new Scale2TimesTransformation(), 
     ...
   }.ToImmutableList(); 

   public void Evaluate(Shape shape)
     => transforms.FirstOrDefault(trans => trans.CanTransformationBeApplied(shape))
                  ?.ApplyTransformation(shape);

}
```